# angular - ¿Cómo calcular la rotación de un marcador en Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

Tengo una página web en la que, ingresando un código y clave, se puede ver la ubicación en tiempo real de una persona con un marcador personalizado (tiene un ícono de flecha).

Quiero que, cuando ese marcador empiece a moverse, la flecha gire hacia esa dirección. Es decir, si se mueve hacia abajo, que la flecha gire y apunte hacia abajo. Así que debo encontrar una fórmula que me ayude a calcular el ángulo de rotación del marcador, pero no he encontrado nada en Internet.

La idea es que se pueda calcular a partir de la coordenada actual y la coordenada nueva.

Actualmente, tengo el siguiente código

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MapsService } from './maps.service';
import { SearchLocationRequest, LocationResponse, UserMarker } from './maps.model';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-maps',
  templateUrl: './maps.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./maps.component.css']
})
export class MapsComponent implements OnInit {

  code : string;
  pass : string;
  loading : boolean;

  latitude : number;
  longitude : number;
  zoom : number;
  marker : UserMarker;
  icon : google.maps.Symbol;

  constructor(private service: MapsService,
    private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      let point = new google.maps.Point(15, 15);
      this.loading = false;
      this.icon = {
        path : 'm33.5 253.5 116-202 115 202s-34-60-115-60-116 60-116 60z', // Dibuja la flecha
        fillColor : 'yellow',
        strokeWeight : 3,
        scale : 0.1,
        anchor : point,
        rotation : 0, //Este valor quiero calcular
      };
      this.disableMarker();
    });
  }

  public updateMarker(res : LocationResponse) {
    this.latitude = res.latitude;
    this.longitude = res.longitude;
    this.marker = {
      latitude : res.latitude,
      longitude : res.longitude
    }
  }
 // Más código    
}
```

Comment: Qué has intentado hasta el momento? 
Es un problema bastante interesante la verdad. En un principio, vas a necesitar si o si 2 puntos en el plano. Justamente la coordenada actual y la coordenada nueva. Con estos 2 puntos en el plano (siendo el plano el mapa) obtienes una recta. Luego con ayuda del sistema de coordenadas geográficas https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordenadas_geogr%C3%A1ficas y el eje de coordenadas cartesianas puedes calcular el ángulo de esa recta con respecto al eje x o al eje y. Con este ángulo ya puedes rotar tu flecha cada vez que hay una nueva coordenada

Comment: @AndresGardiol ya había resuelto el problema, me he ayudado del arcotangente y lo calcula sin problemas, en el que la latitud es la X y la longitud es la Y.

Comment: Que bien, podrías agregar entonces la solución como respuesta a tu pregunta así ayuda a las demas personas?

Comment: @AndresGardiol ya coloqué mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para calcular el ángulo de rotación del marcador, se debe guardar la ubicación actual antes de actualizar a las nuevas coordenadas. Teniendo ambos datos, se procede a calcular el arcotangente de la pendiente calculada a partir de los dos puntos, considerando la *latitud* como la ***coordenada X*** y la *longitud* como la ***coordenada Y***. Una vez calculado el nuevo ángulo de rotación, el ícono debe ser actualizado en su totalidad para que asimile el nuevo valor de rotación, no se puede cambiar este valor individualmente (al menos, en las pruebas que he hecho). El código queda, más o menos, así:

**maps.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MapsService } from './maps.service';
import { SearchLocationRequest, LocationResponse, UserMarker } from './maps.model';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
import { RsaService } from '../security/rsa.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-maps',
  templateUrl: './maps.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./maps.component.css']
})
export class MapsComponent implements OnInit {

  code : string;
  pass : string;
  loading : boolean;

  latitude : number;
  longitude : number;
  zoom : number;

  marker : UserMarker;
  icon : google.maps.Symbol;

  constructor(private service: MapsService,
    private encrypter : RsaService,
    private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.icon = this.setIcon(0);
      this.disableMarker();
    });
  }

  locate() {
    var request : SearchLocationRequest = {
      hash : null,
      code : this.code,
      pass : this.encrypter.encrypt(this.pass)
    };
    this.service.searchLocation(request, this);
  }

  public enableMarker(res : LocationResponse) {
    if (res.status == 'OK') {
      this.zoom = 17;
      this.updateMarker(res);
    } else {
      this.disableMarker();
    }
  }

  public updateMarker(res : LocationResponse) {
    var oldMarker = this.marker
    this.latitude = res.latitude;
    this.longitude = res.longitude;
    this.marker = {
      latitude : res.latitude,
      longitude : res.longitude
    };
    this.icon = this.setIcon(this.service.calculateRotation(oldMarker, this.marker, this.icon.rotation));
  }

  /**
   * Set marker to default position
   */
  public disableMarker() {
    this.latitude = -12.051464989791251;
    this.longitude = -77.03466788860915;
    this.zoom = 15;
    this.marker = null;
    this.service.disable();
  }

  private setIcon(rotation : number) : google.maps.Symbol{
    let point = new google.maps.Point(0, 0);
    return {
      path : environment.iconPath,
      fillColor : 'yellow',
      fillOpacity : 1,
      strokeWeight : 3,
      scale : 0.1,
      anchor : point,
      rotation : rotation,
    };
  }

}
```

**maps.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SearchLocationRequest, LocationResponse, UserMarker } from './maps.model';
import { MapsComponent } from './maps.component';
import { HttpService } from './../web/http.service';
import { WebSocketService } from '../web/web-socket.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MapsService {

  constructor(
    private http : HttpService,
    private ws : WebSocketService
  ) { }

  public searchLocation(request : SearchLocationRequest, ctx : MapsComponent) {
    // Invoca a un servicio web para buscar las nuevas coordenadas
  }

  public calculateRotation(oldMarker : UserMarker, newMarker : UserMarker, oldRotation : number) : number {
    var result : number;
    if (oldMarker != null && newMarker != null) {
      var lon = newMarker.longitude - oldMarker.longitude;
      var lat = newMarker.latitude - oldMarker.latitude;
      // Esto es cuando el marcador no se mueve y evitar la división por cero
      if (lon == 0 && lat == 0) {
        result = oldRotation;
      // Se forma una línea horizontal
      } else if (lon == 0) {
        // Mirando hacia arriba (norte)
        if (lat > 0) {
          result = 0;
        // Mirando hacia abajo (sur)
        } else {
          result = 180;
        }
      // Se forma una línea vertical
      } else if (lat == 0) {
        // Mirando hacia la derecha (este)
        if(lon > 0) {
          result = 90;
        // Mirando hacia la izquierda (oeste)
        } else {
          result = 270;
        }
      } else {
        // Se calcula el arcotangente, tras haber agotado los valores predeterminados
        // Como su resultado es en radianes, hay que convertirlo a grados sexagesimales
        result = Math.atan(lon / lat) * 180 / Math.PI;
        // Se suma para que pueda tener sentido negativo el marcador.
        if (lat < 0) {
          result = result + 180;
        }
      }
    } else {
      result = oldRotation;
    }
    return result;
  }

  // Más código

}
```